# Replacing values in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Our application needs to process XML files. Some times we receive XMLs with values as follows:

```
<DiagnosisStatement>
     <StmtText>ST &</StmtText>
</DiagnosisStatement>
```

Because of `&<` my application is not able to load XML correctly and throwing exception as follows:

```
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 92, position 24.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityName()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityReference()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Transformation.GetEcgTransformer(String filePath, String fileType, String Manufacture, String Producer) in D:\Transformation.cs:line 160
```

Now I need to replace all occurrences of `&<` with 'and<' so that XML can get processed successfully without any exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did in order to load XML with the help of answer given by Botz3000.

```
string oldText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string newText = oldText.Replace("&<", "and<");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, newText, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Xml file is invalid, because `&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;`, so you cannot just load the xml without getting an error. You can do it if you load the file as plain text though:

```
string invalid = File.ReadAllText(filename);
string valid = invalid.Replace("&<", "and<");
File.WriteAllText(filename, valid);
```

If you have control over how the Xml file is generated though, you should fix that issue by either escaping the `&` as `&amp;` or by replacing it with `"and"` as you said.